# jQuery Hide\show closes once opened a new one

Tags: jquery, hide

you know how you open a hide\show spoiler and then open another one and it makes the page really long ?

the solution for it is to make the js check if the class is showing, if yes close the spoiler.

But im not sure how to do this.
This is the js code im using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".hide1").hide();
    $(".spoiler1").show();

    $('.spoiler1').click(function(){
    $(".hide1").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

hide1 = the content that opens on click
spoiler1 = the toggle button.

Spoiler2, 3, 4 are the rest spoilers
so is hide2,3,4 are the rest contents.

this is the live site:

http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html

EXAMPLE:

You click on the first box
this is the boxs area by the way:

http://gyazo.com/5df95ee77b95dfd932eab781955f98f3.png?1349209216

okay, it opened, then click on the second one..
And the content opens yet the first box hasn't closed.

I want the first box to close after opening a new one.
to work like this for all boxs.

how do I do so?

Sorry for the awful grammar by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link each `spoiler` to its corresponding `hide` via custom property:

```
<div id="spoiler1" data-hidden="hide1" class="spoiler">Spoiler 1</div>
<div id="hide1" class="hide">Hide 1</div>
<div id="spoiler2" data-hidden="hide2" class="spoiler">Spoiler 2</div>
<div id="hide2" class="hide">Hide 2</div>
<div id="spoiler3" data-hidden="hide3" class="spoiler">Spoiler 3</div>
<div id="hide3" class="hide">Hide 3</div>
<div id="spoiler4" data-hidden="hide4" class="spoiler">Spoiler 4</div>
<div id="hide4" class="hide">Hide 4</div>​
```

The the behavior would be this:

```
$('.spoiler').click(function() {
    var hiddenid = $(this).data('hidden');
    $('#' + hiddenid).slideToggle();
    $('.hide:not(#' + hiddenid + ')').slideUp();
});​
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/dyUwH/

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work, check it out http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html

Comment: When you click on the button, nothing happens

Comment: I tested it again and it doesn't work, so did my friend on his own site. see my paste bin: http://pastebin.com/Cxk2zdR9

Comment: Adrian, something is really weird happening, look I even put the demo here and it works http://jsfiddle.net/dyUwH/1/ but isn't working on localhost or site? what am I doing wrong? http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to hide all of the divs who's class starts with "hide".  Add the following line of code to your onclick handler.  The selector finds all divs that have a class that starts with "hide" and hides them.  Then just show the one you want.

```
$('div[class^="hide"]').hide();
```

Here's the jquery api doc for this selector, http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing showing and hiding, just do this

```
$('.spoiler').click(function(){

    // if the current is not open then hide opened
    if( !($(this).is(':visible')) ) {
        $('.spoiler:visible').hide();
    }
    // open new one, you know the code here
});
```

there are number of ways to do this, you can easily add a class to open/hide the content, if you add class open to open items then you can easily target the open class and remove it to close it

```
$('.spoiler').click(function(){

    // if the current is not open then hide opened
    if( !($(this).hasClass('open')) ) {
        $('.spoiler').removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');
    } else {
        // remove open if you want to close it
    }

});
```

the spoiler would be closed normally and class open, has like display block or whatever. of course this won't animate, if you want animation then you can use the visible way.

One point I want to make which helped me a lot in my coding. If you add class, it is cleaner and you can use css to control the hide and show in a way. when you want to remove opened item, you DON'T NEEd TO target the specific open you just say

```
$('.spoiler').removeClass('open')
```

so it will remove open if there is a opened class, there is no need to target specifically. Of course if you want to target only the ones has open then

```
$('.spoiler.open').removeClass('open')
```

UPDATE

see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/YE2bY/

Comment: Currently this is my css and html: http://pastebin.com/DjeV9NUB
Could you please explain me what is .spoiler when I use spoiler1,2,3,4 ? I mean could you fix it for me as an example? I really don't understand. I just attempted at adding it and it broke my hide'n'show spoiler 1. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the site: http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html and it doesn't act on click, nothing I dont know what causing this to happen